# Localization of dates in fieldpanel

Tags: wagtail

Is it possible to localize, aka. the `FieldPanel` accepts date as locale data (ex dd-mm-yyyy for french dates) in the wagtailadmin FieldPanel ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible as of Wagtail 1.10. Two new settings `WAGTAIL_DATE_FORMAT` and `WAGTAIL_DATETIME_FORMAT` have been introduced, allowing you to specify the date format you wish to use in the Wagtail admin:

```
WAGTAIL_DATE_FORMAT = '%d.%m.%Y.'
WAGTAIL_DATETIME_FORMAT = '%d.%m.%Y. %H:%M'
```

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10/advanced_topics/settings.html#date-and-datetime-inputs